# Why won't this spec/controller test pass? It did before... (Rails, RSpec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, rspec-rails, rails-postgresql

The following is in my spec/controllers/superadmin/users_controller_spec.rb:

```
  describe "GET index" do
    it "receives the where action twice" do
      User.should_receive(:where).twice
      get :index
    end

    it "assigns @superadmins" do
      get :index
      assigns[:superadmins].should_not be_nil
    end

    it "assigns @admins" do
      get :index
      assigns[:admins].should_not be_nil
    end
  end
```

The following is in my app/controllers/superadmin/users_controller.rb:

```
class Superadmin::UsersController < SuperadminController
  def index
    @superadmins = User.where(:role => 'superadmin')
    @admins = User.where(:role => 'admin')
  end
  ...
end
```

If I recall correctly, this test used to pass. Ever since I set up PostgreSQL as the database for the test and development environments, this test has been failing... not sure why.

Error message:

```
Failures:

  1) Superadmin::UsersController GET index receives the where action twice
     Failure/Error: User.should_receive(:where).twice
       (<User(id: integer, role: string, first_name: string, last_name: string, login: string, email: string, crypted_password: string, password_salt: string, persistence_token: string, single_access_token: string, perishable_token: string, login_count: integer, failed_login_count: integer, last_request_at: datetime, current_login_at: datetime, last_login_at: datetime, current_login_ip: string, last_login_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, restaurant_id: integer, organization_id: integer) (class)>).where(any args)
           expected: 2 times
           received: 0 times
     # ./spec/controllers/superadmin/users_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Superadmin::UsersController GET index assigns @superadmins
     Failure/Error: assigns[:superadmins].should_not be_nil
       expected: not nil
            got: nil
     # ./spec/controllers/superadmin/users_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Superadmin::UsersController GET index assigns @admins
     Failure/Error: assigns[:admins].should_not be_nil
       expected: not nil
            got: nil
     # ./spec/controllers/superadmin/users_controller_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>
```

Assistance appreciated!

Comment: Which test is failing? What is the failure message? It's going to be very hard for anyone to answer your question without more info.

Comment: Ah how could I forget that - adding it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything in the code you've provided that would make those tests fail. Do you have any before_filters that might be failing? I'm guessing that controller requires authentication. Are you setting that up in your tests in a before block?

Comment: Oh - the lack of authentication is the problem! Thanks for your intuition. I guess I should run my tests more frequently so I have a better idea of what breaks my tests. It was absurd to think changing databases would be the cause - I must have (1) added validation and (2)  changed dbs without running my tests in between. Lesson learned. :]

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, but I don't see what it adds to the table... you mean https://github.com/rspec/rspec/wiki/autotest ?